# A Butcher's Brawl

Tags: wordplay, cryptic-crosswords

Beastly brawl begets batch of black and blatantly blue butchers. Crack the coming crossword to create curious clues, then tally total troublemakers that tussled:

[image]

#### Clues:

**Across:**
1. Vote to mention cutoff by heartless ultimatum (10)
6. Warden tried to conceal burning (6)
8. Marry at last after smoother, insincere praise (8)
10. Beer at disastrous discount (6)
11. Announced elder had misbehaved (8)
14. Housetop with love for returning (4)
16. Bill from returning container (3)
17. First off, be angry fruit (3)
20. Some numerology has portent (4)
21. Script a cross-part idea (8)
24. Mess up South Pole's falsely missing shop (6)
25. Star polish's a combination of light and heat (8)
26. Avi's military ends nasty elfs (6)
27. Direct scare over drunk Thor (10)
**Down:**
1. Religious upheaval's quota has Exodia's first shape (11)
2. Barf bag lets nasty surprise (11)
3. Intro to a vicious cycle (8)
4. First servant's military rank regulated mood (9)
5. A poem's terminal (5)
7. Perfect leader missing unit for volume (4)
9. Savage search engine (5)
12. Shrinking excavation site has small tibia (11)
13. Bury inside: desist fabrication for fairness (11)
15. Fight upset, if it's reversed in a scrape (9)
18. Could be mess, or be stamp user (8)
19. Passive contraction starts trampling on humanity (5)
22. Daisy's steer view (5)
23. Bar drink (over ten) (4)

After approaching an answer, I ascertained an assortment of assertions:

- Reinterpreted, remark reveals reason for ruckus
- Parsing primary phrase of pair provides posterior part
- Identifying identical interrelation is indispensable to infer incendiaries
- Decipher directly to specify single symbol

Answer (score 6):

Nearly complete answer – need some help with the final answer.

Across

> ```
> 1. Vote to mention cutoff by heartless ultimatum (10)       REFERENDUM - REFER + END + U...M
> 6. Warden tried to conceal burning (6)                      ARDENT - WARDEN*
> 8. Marry at last after smoother, insincere praise (8)       FLATTERY - FLATTER + (marr)Y
> 10. Beer at disastrous discount (6)                         REBATE - (BEER AT)*
> 11. Announced elder had misbehaved (8)                      HERALDED - (ELDER HAD)*
> 14. Housetop with love for returning (4)                    ROOF - O in FOR<
> 16. Bill from returning container (3)                       NIB - BIN< 
> 17. First off, be angry fruit (3)                           UME - (f)UME
> 20. Some numerology has portent (4)                         OMEN - s_OME N_umerology
> 21. Script a cross-part idea (8)                            NOTATION - NOTION around AT?
> 24. Mess up South Pole's falsely missing shop (6)           TOUSLE - (SOUTH POLE'S - shop)*
> 25. Star polish's a combination of light and heat (8)       SUNSHINE - SUN + SHINE
> 26. Avi's military ends nasty elfs (6)                      MYSELF - M(ilitar)Y + ELFS*
> 27. Direct scare over drunk Thor (10)                       FORTHRIGHT - THOR* in FRIGHT
> ```

Down

> ```
> 1. Religious upheaval's quota has Exodia's first shape (11) REFORMATION
>                                                               - R(E... +  FORM)ATION
> 2. Barf bag lets nasty surprise (11)                        FLABBERGAST - (BARF BAG LETS)*
> 3. Intro to a vicious cycle (8)                             ROTATION - (INTRO TO A)*
> 4. First servant's military rank regulated mood (9)         MAJORDOMO - MAJOR + MOOD*
> 5. A poem's terminal (5)                                    ANODE - AN ODE
> 7. Perfect leader missing unit for volume (4)               DEAL - (i)DEAL
> 9. Savage search engine (5)                                 YAHOO - ddef.
> 12. Shrinking excavation site has small tibia (11)          DIMINISHING - (MINI + SHIN) in DIG
> 13. Bury inside: desist fabrication for fairness (11)       DISINTEREST - INTER in DESIST*
> 15. Fight upset, if it's reversed in a scrape (9)           FISTICUFF - IF< ITS< CUFF
> 18. Could be mess, or be stamp user (8)                     EMBOSSER - (MESS OR BE)*
> 19. Passive contraction starts trampling on humanity (5)    TONUS - T... + ON + US
> 22. Daisy's steer view (5)                                  OXEYE - OX + EYE
> 23. Bar drink (over ten) (4)                                AXLE - A(X)LE
> ```

The grid

> ```
>      R E F E R E N D U M       A
>      E   L   O         A R D E N T
>      F L A T T E R Y   J   E   O
>      O   B   A     A   O   A   D
>      R E B A T E   H E R A L D E D
>      M   E   I     O   D     I   I
>      A   R O O F   O   O     M   S
>      T   G   N I B   U M E   I   I
>      I   A     S   T   O M E N   N
>      O   S     T   O     B   I   T
>      N O T A T I O N   T O U S L E
>        X   X   C   U     S   H   R
>        E   L   U   S U N S H I N E
>      M Y S E L F         E   N   S
>        E       F O R T H R I G H T
> ```

The shaded cells

> From dark purple via red and yellow to green, the shaded regions spell:
>
>      **F before a bout for team**
>
>  This looks like another cryptic clue. I guess we're looking for the name of a sports team here, probably starting with F or FA, but I got nothin'.
>
>  (Perhaps I got the ordering wrong. It's not strictly Richard of York, but this order makes the best sense to me.)

Comment: rot13(Jura fbzrguvat vf zvffvat, EBLTOVI trgf fcyvg vagb gjb cnegf. Svaq jung pbaarpgf gur gjb cnegf. Nqqvgvbanyyl, ohgpuref jbhyq arire svtug sbe n GRNZ - gurl zvtug svtug sbe fbzrguvat ryfr, gubhtu.)

Comment: Given 'butcher' in the title and going rainbow-esque order, I get rot13(n obhg sbe zrng _____ orsber S) noting that one color is missing... still working on it

Comment: @Avi  rot13(n obhg sbe zrng) could be a rot13("orrs orrs") but I'm not sure if that matters :D

Comment: @TwoBitOperation rot13(Jryy, lbh qvq vqragvsl gur zrng :)) - your first comment was completely correct.

Comment: Another interpretation of the two parts is ordered and split as @TwoBitOperation notes: rot13(*N OBHG SBE ZRNG* [jura nccyvrq gb] *ORSBER S* => Nobhg "SBE" [vf] zrng => "OR(sbe)RS")

Comment: @Alconja rot13(Pbeerpg! Ernyvmvat obgu gubfr pbzovangvbaf rkvfg yrnqf gb na vagraqrq nafjre, juvpu pna or qrfpevorq ol “ORSBER S” - fvzcyl gnyyl gubfr gebhoyrznxref, abj)